# Java Sound format not supported

Tags: java, audio, recording

When using the following code: http://pastebin.com/5iVnttiP

I receive this error:

```
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
    at com.AIComputer.model.Recorder.<init>(Recorder.java:124)
    at com.AIComputer.AIComputer.main(AIComputer.java:7)
```

Now I did some research and found out that not all sound cards support every format, however when running this demo: http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/samples/JavaSoundDemo/
I managed to produce a recording using the exact same parameters (linear, 16000, 16, signed, little endian, stereo).

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here (also since I'm still a beginner at Java coding).

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think I've ever used that AudioFormat constructor. I find it odd that they ask for the samplerate and framerate -- that's redundant and ambiguous. Try the other constructor and see if that works.

Comment: do you have an example for me? As I stated I'm just a beginner in Java.

Comment: There is another constructor: AudioFormat(float sampleRate, int sampleSizeInBits, int channels, boolean signed, boolean bigEndian) Try that with AudioFormat( 16000, 2, true, false );

Comment: first eclipse gives the error that a sample rate must be added, doing so and running the program again will result in the same error as above.

Comment: what's the version of the JDK you're using? btw java package names should use only lower case...

Comment: If you doubt you might have sound-card related problem (hardware) you should provide your sound card model, the driver you're using (the exact version of it) also OS would be nice.

Comment: Can you say from which line on YOUR code this exception is thrown? [The docs of LineUnavailableException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineUnavailableException.html) says *"This situation arises most commonly when a requested line is already in use by another application"*, and you're getting two lines in your code. I just wanted to know if this comes from first or second line opening..

Comment: JDK version: 1.7.0_05 - Sound card is a onboard from my MSI h55m-e33 with as far as I know the latest version of the driver, also I'm running Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you say from which line on YOUR code this exception is thrown?

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineUnavailableException.html) of LineUnavailableException says

> This situation arises most commonly when a requested line is already in use by another application.

You're opening two lines in your code. When you try to open the second one, the existence of the first one blocks it.

Comment: @xorinzor So what changes did you need to make exactly?

Comment: @trusktr I think it was at line 131 where I try to open the same device twice

Comment: @xorinzor Oh for sure. Thanks. I ended up using the amazing Beads sound library (beadsproject.net). It solved all problems (though I'm only playing sound, not recording).