# while loop error with jToggleButton : JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, while-loop

I coded a function for Audio capturing with while loop in netbeans. but last curly bracket in the while loop code shows compilation error and I don't know why (the line is mentioned in code by comment). Anyhow I run the project, and it says "compile with errors" and ran. After running the app, I click the `jToggleButton` to start the coded function(Audio Capturing) and it worked successfully. after I click the `jToggleButton` again to stop the function(Audio Capturing), it gets stopped also. but after this second click, the netbeans output terminal shows some errors as well. So, I tried to find what is the issue, but still couldn't identified what's going wrong with code. I hope, I can get help from here.

> Error logs :

```
 javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian not supported.
 at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:121)
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:153)
 at javaapplication1.NewJFrame1$2.run(NewJFrame1.java:83)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

> Code:

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;


public class NewJFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public NewJFrame1() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jToggleButton1.setText("jToggleButton1");
    jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jPanel1.add(jToggleButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(130, 70, -1, -1));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}                  

private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

 Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()  
 {                                     
    @Override                          
    public void run()                  
    {                                  

AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(8000.0f, 16, 1, true, true);
{TargetDataLine microphone;
SourceDataLine speakers;

try {
    microphone = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);

    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    microphone.open(format);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int numBytesRead;
    int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
    byte[] data = new byte[microphone.getBufferSize() / 5];
    microphone.start();


    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    speakers = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
    speakers.open(format);
    speakers.start();

    while(jToggleButton1.isSelected()){
        numBytesRead = microphone.read(data, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
        speakers.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);

    }
    speakers.drain();
    speakers.close();
    microphone.close();

    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      }
    }

 }         // This Carly Bracket shows red underline. but I don't know whyv?!

t.start();    
  }         
}                                              


public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }



    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration                  
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;

}
```

Comment: There error indicates that your sound library can't handle the format of the sound file.

Comment: You need to add ); behind your underlined bracket to close your new Thread

Comment: Thank you @KilledByCheese. I got it. and now that error fixed. but that netbeans output terminal shows errors(mentioned in question) are still have. can you help me at that also...? I tried, but still no idea.

Comment: Hello @SteveSmith, Then how can I fix it...? can you help me ?

Comment: @user7560586 Do not remove the part of original question that gets answered and accept an anwer if it is solved. Because other might want to refer it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

// This Carly Bracket shows red underline. but I don't know whyv?!

Read the compiler error, it says to close this statement with **);**

Because you have not closed the below statement:

```
 Thread t = new Thread ( new Runnable()
```

Comment: Thank you much @Rohit Gulati, I got it clearly. and now that error fixed. but that netbeans output terminal shows errors(mentioned in question) are still have. can you help me at that also...? I tried, but still no idea.

Comment: @user7560586 could you please try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12029800/5803493) as the problem mentioned there is exactly same.

Comment: @user7560586 As mentioned in the above link you are opening two two lines in your code. When you try to open the second one, the existence of the first one blocks it. microphone.open(format); and speakers.open(format);

Comment: @user7560586I am also new to this but I tried to run your code and when I commented out code "microphone.open(format)", then it is now throwing the excpetion. Tried to open one line only. Check if your functionality works as expected after doing this.