# create a crypted voip application

Tags: java

I realized a voip application encrypted with the algorithms AES and RC4 then when I execute the application and I encrypt the voice with the two algorithms it works normal but when I add the algorithm ECC it works for the first time and after it displays this error and then nothing of these algorithms works
here is some of my code that executes voice transfer and encrypted with ECC

```
   public VOIPClientEC(String ip, int port) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        try {
            client = new Socket(ip, port);

            this.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public VOIPClientEC(Socket s) {
        client = s;

        this.start();
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            //long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            OutputStream o = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(o);
            //dos.writeLong(t);
            InputStream inp = client.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inp);
          //  long time = dis.readLong();
            EllipticCurveAlgorithm algorithm = new EllipticCurveAlgorithm();
            PointProccessor processor = new PointProccessor();
            long pri = 1234567891;
            Point pub = processor.multiply(pri, algorithm.base);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(o);
            os.writeObject(pub.getX());
            os.writeObject(pub.getY());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inp);
            Object px = ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(px);
            Object py = ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(py);
            Point p = new Point((long)px, (long)py);
            inp = null;
            dos = null;
            dis = null;
            class VOIPEcouteur extends Thread {

                private BufferedInputStream buffis = null;
                private InputStream is = null;

                private byte[] data;
                private int count,
                         cE;

                private AudioFormat audio = null;
                private SourceDataLine ligneSource = null;

                private AudioInputStream audiois = null;

                public VOIPEcouteur() {
                    try {

                        buffis = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                        //configuration Audio
                        audio = confAudio();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }

                }

                public void run() {

                    data = new byte[VOIP_BUFFER];
                    try {

                        while ((count = buffis.read(data, 0, data.length)) !=
                                -1 && !boolStopTalking) {

                            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

                            audiois = new AudioInputStream(is, audio,
                                    data.length / audio.getFrameSize());

                            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                                    SourceDataLine.class, audio);

                            ligneSource = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(
                                    dataLineInfo);

                            ligneSource.open(audio);
                            ligneSource.start();

                            while ((count = audiois.read(data, 0, data.length)) !=
                                    -1) {

                                if (count > 0) {
                                   byte[] s = algorithm.decrypt(data, pri);
                                    ligneSource.write(s, 0, s.length);
                                    cE++;
                                   /* if (cE == 1){       
                                        tc3 = System.currentTimeMillis()-time;
                                        System.out.println("temp d'execution EC : "+tc3); 
                                    }*/
                                }
                            }
                        }


                       // ligneSource.flush();
                        ligneSource.drain();
                        ligneSource.stop();
                        ligneSource.close();
                        client.close();
                    } catch (IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }

            class VOIPParleur extends Thread {
                private BufferedOutputStream buffos = null;                    
                private TargetDataLine ligneCible = null;
                private AudioFormat audio = null;
                private byte[] data;
                private int count;

                public VOIPParleur() {
                    try {
                        buffos = new BufferedOutputStream(client.
                                getOutputStream());

                        audio = confAudio();

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }

                }

                public void run() {
                    try {
                        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                                TargetDataLine.class, audio);


                        ligneCible = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(
                                dataLineInfo);



                        ligneCible.open(audio);


                        ligneCible.start();
                        data = new byte[VOIP_BUFFER];
                        boolStopTalking = false;

                        try {

                            while (!boolStopTalking) {

                                count = ligneCible.read(data, 0, data.length);
                                if (count > 0) {
                                   byte [] s = algorithm.encrypt(data, p);
                                   buffos.write(s, 0, data.length);
                                }
                            }

                            buffos.close();
                            ligneCible.stop();
                            ligneCible.close();

                            client.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(VOIPClientEC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }

            new VOIPParleur().start();
            new VOIPEcouteur().start();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VOIPClientEC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private AudioFormat confAudio() {
        //configuration copi�e

        //8000,11025,16000,22050,44100
        float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
        //8,16
        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
        //1,2
        int channels = 2;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = false;

        return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
                               channels, signed,
                               bigEndian);
    }
}
```

and that is the error

> chat.VOIPClientEC$1VOIPParleur run GRAVE: null
>   javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format
>   PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not
>   supported.    at
>   com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:121)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:153)
>     at chat.VOIPClientEC$1VOIPParleur.run(VOIPClient.java:759)
>
> Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   chat.VOIPClientEC$1VOIPEcouteur.run(VOIPClient.java:720)

Comment: maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915469/java-sound-format-not-supported

Comment: I saw it but I don't understand the solution

Comment: You should split each classes and monitor different thread states. What is possible is you run multiple instances of threads in a same time.

Comment: Can you explain to me more your solution. do you meen that I have to use the monitors ?